# Integrate the payment status webhook in globalpayments

Tags: global-payments-api

I am new to **globalpayments** & currently working on it. I'm using credit cards for payment. Now I want to make a webhook for success and failed transaction but from the portal I am unable to do that. I have gone through the stripe webhook creation. It's simple and easy but is there any way to do that in **globalpayments**?

I am new to **globalpayments** & currently working on it. I'm using credit cards for payment. Now I want to make a webhook for success and failed transaction but from the portal I am unable to do that. I have gone through the stripe webhook creation. It's simple and easy but is there any way to do that in globalpayments?